# how to programatically assign a bunch of variables within a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-assignment

Given a character vector `vars` and a list of data frames `d`, I want to
make sure every data frame in `d` has all the columns named in `vars`.
Let's say some of the columns are missing in one data frame, then I create
those columns in the data frame and fill them with `NA`s.

However when I do this by using `assign` I get some strange results:

```
> vars <- c('y','z')
> b <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=3:1)
> b
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 2
3 3 1
> within(b, for (v in vars) assign(v, NA))
  a b  z  y v
1 1 3 NA NA z
2 2 2 NA NA z
3 3 1 NA NA z
```

You can see that I managed to create columns `z` and `y` using this method,
but there's also an extra volumn `v` which I don't know where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way that's in the spirit of your original code.

```
for(v in vars) { b[[v]] <- NA }
```

The reason you're getting the extra `v` in your version is that any variable that is created in the call to `within` gets added to that data frame, and the for loop creates that variable. If you remove it at the end it will go away. However, watch out for the case that your `vars` variable include `v`.

```
within(b, {for (v in vars) assign(v, NA); rm(v) })
```

You might also make `vars` include all the variables and just get the ones you want to keep with `setdiff`.

```
vars <- c('a','b','y','z')
b <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=3:1)
for(v in setdiff(vars, names(b))) { b[[v]] <- NA }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
missingCols <- setdiff(vars, names(b))
naColumn <- function(x)rep(NA, nrow(b))

cbind(b, sapply(missingCols, naColumn, USE.NAMES=TRUE))

  a b  y  z
1 1 3 NA NA
2 2 2 NA NA
3 3 1 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
list2env(split(rep(NA,2*nrow(b)),vars),envir=.GlobalEnv)
 cbind(b,mget(vars))
#   a b  y  z
# 1 1 3 NA NA
# 2 2 2 NA NA
# 3 3 1 NA NA
```

or

```
cbind(b,mget(setdiff(vars,names(b))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
setDT(b)            ## convert data.frame to data.table
set(b, j=vars, value=NA_integer_)

#    a b  y  z
# 1: 1 3 NA NA
# 2: 2 2 NA NA
# 3: 3 1 NA NA
```

Note all `set*` functions in `data.table` (and `:=` operator) operates by reference, meaning there was no (unnecessary) copy being made here.

In case you'd like to work with `data.frame`, you can just convert this back to a `data.frame`. In [v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) (currently development version), there's a function `setDF` that's implemented to get back to a `data.frame` from `data.table` by reference (as opposed to the traditional `as.data.frame(.)` function that'll result in a copy).

Putting it all together (if you want a `data.frame` at the end)

```
## 1.9.3
setDF(set(setDT(b), j=vars, value=NA_integer_))
#   a b  y  z
# 1 1 3 NA NA
# 2 2 2 NA NA
# 3 3 1 NA NA
```

Once again, no (deep) copies were made.